# Run-time error '424' getElementById

Tags: vba, web-scraping, getelementbyid

I am trying to automate a process where I need to enter some data in a website textbox. I reused a code that works well for a different site, but here I get a "runtime error 424: object required" when I attempt to enter a value using GetElementByID

This is the link to the site:
http://www.e-post.co.il/?page_id=723

(I am interested in updating the *upper* text box)

and the code:

```
Sub main()
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "http://www.e-post.co.il/?page_id=723"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
objIE.Document.getElementById("num_with_letters").Value = "IP1210665"   
End Sub
```

Comment: @QHarr could you post an answer which explains this issue in detail? Even if it does not solve my problem I would like to understand it better. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I didn't spot this at the time. Your element is within an iframe. You can use the iframe src url direct

```
Public Sub EnterInfo()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://run.hfd.co.il/run_public3/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementById("num_with_letters").Value = "IP1210665"

        Stop      
   End With
End Sub
```

If you want to use the original url you need to navigate the iframe as follows:

```
.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("btn_eur")
```